# Determine whether Bash variable is one of several values

Tags: bash, validation

Assume there are three valid values for a Bash variable `$x`: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. How does one write an expression to determine whether `$x` is one of these values? In Python, for example, one might write:

```
x in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Is there a Bash equivalent, or is it necessary to perform three comparisons? Again, in Python, one could write:

```
x == 'foo' or x == 'bar' or x == 'baz'
```

What's the correct way to express the above in Bash?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
case $x in
    foo|bar|baz) echo is valid ;;
    *) echo not valid ;;
esac
```

A bit more complicated

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $x == @(foo|bar|baz) ]]; then
    echo is valid
else
    echo not valid
fi
```

More complicated:

```
is_valid() {
    local valid=( foo bar baz )
    local value=$1
    for elem in "${valid[@]}"; do
        [[ $value == $elem ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

if is_valid "$x"; then
    echo is valid
else
    echo not valid
fi
```

Comment: I didn't know about `shopt -s extglob`. Thanks!

Comment: And in this context, it's not required: from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) "When the ‘`==`’ and ‘`!=`’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), **_as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled_**."

Answer (score 8):

Use a case statement:

```
var=bar
case $var in
  foo | bar | baz )
    echo "Matches"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: How could i miss that one. Of course it's the good way do do it. +1

Answer (score 7):

One can use `||` for alternation between `[[` and `]]`:

```
if [[ $x == foo || $x == bar || $x == baz ]] ; then
  echo valid
else
  echo invalid
fi
```

Comment: +1, but note that not quoting the right operands means they're interpreted not as literals, but as _patterns_ (globs) - no difference in this specific case, but it's important to be aware of the distinction.